# MQL4 Trade feed as a WEB API

Tags: wordpress, rest, mql4

Does someone had any idea or created a webservice REST API in JSON format, which another remote server can fetch the data from.

Just need some beginner's lesson how to setup it on MQL4. My client needs this kind of service, which we will then output on a WordPress as Widgets.

I want to know how our WordPress server can access this. MQL4 had this `WebRequest()` function and planning to use it, but don't know where to start.

Comment: It is rather difficult to answer your question here, because usually minimum,complete and verifiable example (MCVE) is required in order to comment. You know the function so what is the problem? read the documentation and use it

Comment: Commercial Projects ought be rather contracted, not asked to get volunteer-sponsored.

Comment: or mt4 part can be subcontracted :)

Comment: hey guys, im not asking to create it for me, just asking if somehow someone could give some idea how it work. but no worries already figure it out. thanks, a lot for the time, much appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of options possible.

you can:
a. create web api call to save incoming data (ticks/candles) into db.
create mql4 script to send data via api.

or
b.  create c++ / c# dll to save data into db.
separately create web api in language of your choice to read from db.

or
c. save file into web accessible folder in format you like and read the file from word press.